# Передача объекта по ссылке

Tags: javascript

Объекты передаются по ссылке.Так почему не меняется значенеи переменной good?

```
var good={};
var str=good;
console.log(str);//{}
var str='bad';
console.log(str);//bad!!!!!!
console.log(good)//{}!!!!!!
```

пр2

```
 var good={};
    var str=good;
    str.name='bad';
    console.log(good)//Object { name="bad"}
    console.log('str='+str)//str=[object Object]
```

Comment: Простые переменные копируются по значению, а объекты - по ссылке.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var good={};
var str=good; // str указывает на good
console.log(str);//{} - то же самое что и good
var str='bad'; // два раза var подряд. у вас уже объявлена переменная str. 
               // тут переменная стала указывать на строку, а не на good
console.log(str);//bad!!!!!! да, выводится строка, на которую указывает str
console.log(good)//{}!!!!!! объект good никуда не делся

var good={};
var str=good;// str указывает на good. 
             // т.е. есть две переменные указывающие на один объект
str.name='bad';// меняете в объекте поле. аналогично было бы good.name='bad'
console.log(good)//Object { name="bad"} все верно объект изменили
console.log('str='+str)//str=[object Object] - тут тот же самый объект, просто toString() у него вывел для вас [object Object]
```

Comment: с п а с и б о

Answer (score 3):

С JS знаком слабо, но очень похоже на поведение в питоне: в первом примере переменной str присвоено новое значение, поэтому она ссылается уже на другой объект - строку 'bad', а переменная good по-прежнему ссылается на пустой объект.
Во втором же случае переменная str по-прежнему указывает на тот же объект и изменяет его атрибут. В связи с чем и в good теперь можно найти атрибут name.

Answer (score 1):

coffeeScript code

```
# result method
Object::r = (v) ->
    s=@
    st='global.'+v+'={'+'s'+'}'
    re=(eval st)
    str='global.'+v+'=re["s"]'
    eval(str)
    @


[1..10].r('a').
    map( (v) -> 'lorem_ipsum_'+v.toString() ).r('ar').
    join("__").r('s').
    split("__").reverse().r('arr')

console.log("\n")
console.log(a); console.log("\n")
console.log(ar); console.log("\n")
console.log(s); console.log("\n")
console.log(arr); console.log("\n")
```

[image: screenShot]

Comment: Ув-мый Aliaksandr, пожалуйста, вставьте в ответ вывод как текст, а не изображение. [**Почему это желательно**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Спасибо.